# tail -1 file1 >> file2 without \n

Tags: tail

it might be simple but after looking around I could not find a way to resolve my issue,
I am recovering the last line from file1 using tail -1 file1 and want to add it to an existing file that is a table, so I can fill columns (that are separated by a comma) by doing:

```
tail -1 file1 >> file2
echo "," >> file2
tail -1 file3 >> file2
echo "," >> file2
....
```

but my issue is that each new entry is done in a new row.
how can I prevent this?

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tail -1` extracts the last line of the specified file, including the newline character that ends the last line. You need to strip off this newline character.

A command substitution `$(…)` strips off trailing newlines. So put the `tail` calls in a command substitution.

```
printf '%s,%s\n' "$(tail -n1 file1)" "$(tail -n1 file3)" >>file2
```

Depending on your shell and your data, `echo "$(tail -n1 file1),$(tail -n1 file3)" >>file2` may or may not work. It's guaranteed to work if the first column doesn't start with `-` and no column contains a backslash.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! it was quiet frustrating ....

Comment: @otaolafr if this answer solved your problem please use the tickmark ✔ to accept it

Comment: Sorry I have a small issue, when I add a third argument it does not add to the same line, I use ***printf '%s,%s,%s\n' "$(tail -n1 nbCell.txt)" "$(tail -n1 volume.csv)" "$(tail -n1 area.csv)"  >>log.csv*** but I get two in the same line and the comma and the last value in a second row

Comment: the issue is comming from the csv that they have an empty line at the end. it is driving me crazy..... if i use tail -1 area.csv  in the terminal i have a value as result.
if I use tail -1 area.csv > area.csv after the file has an empty line alone. I can not understand these behavior, as I would expect or print an empty line with the first code or in the second case finish with a file with only the last value.

Comment: @otaolafr Make sure your files don't contain Windows line endings. `$(…)` removes the newline (LF) character at the end, but Windows puts an additional CR character at the end of each line which Unix utilities won't remove. You can use `… | tr -d '\r'` to remove CR characters if this is an issue. If one of your input files has an empty line at the end, `$(tail -n1 …)` would be empty.

Comment: Actually the issue was that the Csv files had some characters that were not showing cat -a